# Pretty URLs (without '#') on scalajs-react Play app

Tags: scala.js, playframework-2.5, scalajs-react

In the documentation for `scalajs-react`'s router, @japgolly [cautions users of the library that starting URLs with '/' slashes requires additional server configuration](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/blob/master/doc/ROUTER.md#caution).

To allow pretty URLs without `#`, so far I've tried to write a catch-all route in the Play `routes` file like the following:

```
# Home page
GET     /          com.xyz.controllers.Application.index(path: String = "")

...
# Catch-all route
GET     /*path     com.xyz.controllers.Application.index(path: String)
```

with the matching index path in `Application.scala`

```
def index(path: String = "") = Action {
  Ok(views.html.index("Title"))
}
```

and finally the routes declared using `RouterConfigDsl` in the front-end:

```
def create = Router(BaseUrl.until_#, RouterConfigDsl[Loc].buildConfig { dsl =>
    import dsl._

    ( emptyRule
    | staticRoute(root, DashboardLoc)                   ~> render(filler("Dashboard"))
    | staticRoute("purchase-orders", PurchaseOrdersLoc) ~> render(filler("Purchase Orders"))
    | staticRoute("dashboard", DashboardLoc)            ~> render(filler("Dashboard"))
    | staticRoute("items", ItemsLoc)                    ~> render(ItemGallery())
    | staticRoute("customers", CustomersLoc)            ~> render(filler("Customers"))
    | staticRoute("sales-orders", SalesOrdersLoc)       ~> render(filler("Sales Orders"))
    | staticRoute("preorders", PreordersLoc)            ~> render(filler("Pre-orders"))
    ).notFound(redirectToPage(DashboardLoc)(Redirect.Replace))
     .setTitle(l => s"XYZ | ${l.name}")
}.renderWith(layout))
```

Running locally, I have the app auto-redirecting to `DashboardLoc` at `localhost:9000/dashboard` and the other static routes work when clicking on them within the web app but fail when reloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem after all was using `BaseUrl.until#` instead of `BaseUrl.fromWindowOrigin_/`. Now all the routes work as expected.